# how to see what attribute is giving me this error: value too long for type character varying(255)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake, varchar

I'm trying to deploy my rails app with heroku.  I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` and that worked fine.  Then I tried running `heroku run rake db:seed` and I got this error: `value too long for type character varying(255)`.

I looked through my code and I'm pretty sure that all the string attributes are less than 255 characters.  How do I see which attribute is giving me the error?

```
~/collegeanswerz >>  heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.6374
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
Migrating to CreateColleges (20130529230046)
Migrating to AddDetailsToCollege (20130529231454)
Migrating to AddMoredetailsToCollege (20130530024157)
Migrating to AddAaaToCollege (20130530140803)
Migrating to AddBbbToCollege (20130530141312)
Migrating to AddCccToCollege (20130530142345)
Migrating to AddDddToCollege (20130530142537)
Migrating to AddNameToCollege (20130530145608)
Migrating to AddUrlToColleges (20130607205230)
Migrating to DeleteActFromColleges (20130608162648)
Migrating to AddActToColleges (20130608162707)
Migrating to RemoveActFromColleges (20130608162808)
Migrating to AddCostToColleges (20130608193301)
Migrating to AddLinksToColleges (20130608232148)
Migrating to AddScholToColleges (20130608232522)
Migrating to AddMapToColleges (20130609222024)
Migrating to AddHousingToColleges (20130609235838)
Migrating to AddFwToColleges (20130610003429)
Migrating to AddDormsToColleges (20130610145106)
Migrating to AddMajorsooToColleges (20130610154704)
Migrating to RemoveMajorsooFromColleges (20130610155336)
Migrating to AddMajorsoooToColleges (20130610155625)
Migrating to AddDormurlsToColleges (20130613023113)
~/collegeanswerz >>  heroku run rake db:seed
Running `rake db:seed` attached to terminal... up, run.6256
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
rake aborted!
PGError: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)
: UPDATE "colleges" SET "url" = 'university-of-pittsburgh', "public" = 'Public', "years" = '4-year', "category" = 'National University', "calendar" = 'Semester', "location" = 'Pittsburgh, PA', "setting" = 'Large City (250-500k)', "retention" = 90, "graduation4" = 57, "graduation6" = 79, "degrees" = 'Certificate, Bachelors, Masters, Doctoral', "rotc" = 'Air Force, Army, Navy', "sat_submit" = 89, "act_submit" = 41, "sat_math_25" = 600, "sat_math_75" = 690, "sat_reading_25" = 570, "sat_reading_75" = 690, "sat_writing_25" = 560, "sat_writing_75" = 660, "sat_composite_25" = 1130, "sat_composite_75" = 1320, "act_math_25" = 25, "act_math_75" = 30, "act_reading_25" = 25, "act_reading_75" = 31, "act_writing_25" = 7, "act_writing_75" = 9, "act_composite_25" = 25, "act_composite_75" = 30, "acceptance_rate" = 58, "enrolled" = 32, "gpa375" = 71, "gpa35" = 15, "gpa325" = 8, "gpa3" = 4, "gpa25" = 2, "high_school_tenth" = 54, "high_school_quarter" = 86, "high_school_half" = 99, "sat_math_700" = 25, "sat_math_600" = 53, "sat_math_500" = 21, "sat_math_400" = 1, "sat_math_300" = 0, "sat_reading_700" = 24, "sat_reading_600" = 42, "sat_reading_500" = 32, "sat_reading_400" = 2, "sat_reading_300" = 0, "sat_writing_700" = 14, "sat_writing_600" = 45, "sat_writing_500" = 37, "sat_writing_400" = 4, "sat_writing_300" = 0, "act_composite_30" = 33, "act_composite_24" = 58, "act_composite_18" = 8, "act_composite_12" = 1, "act_math_30" = 40, "act_math_24" = 46, "act_math_18" = 13, "act_math_12" = 1, "act_reading_30" = 0, "act_reading_24" = 0, "act_reading_18" = 0, "act_reading_12" = 0, "very_important" = 'Academic GPA|Rigor of secondary school record|Standardized Test Scores', "considered" = 'Application Essay|Character/Personal Qualities|Class Rank|Extracurricular Activities|First Generation College Student|Geographical Residence|Level of Applicant''s Interest|Racial/Ethnic Status|Recommendations|State Residency|Talent/Ability|Volunteer Work|Work Experience', "student_faculty" = '14 to 1', "class_20" = 42, "class_49" = 39, "class_50" = 18, "majors" = 'business/marketing: 15%|social sciences: 14%|health professions: 11%|english: 10%|engineering: 9%|psychology: 8%|biology: 7%|history: 5%', "law" = 3, "business" = 1, "medical" = 4, "other_grad" = 28, "us_news_ranking" = 58, "top_25_grad" = 'Physical Therapy (3)|Speech-Language Pathology (8)|Library and Information Studies (10)|Social Work (11)|Medicine (15)|Education (24)', "requirements" = 'http://www.asundergrad.pitt.edu/requirements/gened.html', "majors_offered_link" = 'http://www.pitt.edu/academics/undergraduate', "ap_credit" = 'http://www.oafa.pitt.edu/pdf/CreditAPIBExam.pdf', "enrollment" = 18427, "graduate_enrollment" = 10339, "in_state" = 68, "out_of_state" = 32, "male" = 49, "female" = 51, "ethnicity" = 'white: 77%|hispanic/latino: 2%|asian: 8%|black: 5%|2 or more races: 3%|non-resident aliens: 3%|other: 2%', "frats" = 12, "sororities" = 10, "on_campus" = 45, "freshman_on_campus" = 97, "in_state_tuition" = 16590, "out_of_state_tuition" = 26280, "room_and_board" = 9870, "with_need_got_aid" = 68, "got_need_fully_met" = 7, "percent_need_met" = 59, "scholarships" = 41, "loans" = 59, "cost_30" = 17326, "cost_48" = 19950, "cost_75" = 23636, "cost_110" = 26410, "cost_111" = 26985, "scholarships_link" = 'http://www.oafa.pitt.edu/universityschlrs.aspx', "map" = '<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=university+of+pittsburgh&amp;aq=&amp;sll=40.444261,-79.970448&amp;sspn=0.142165,0.251656&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=university+of+pittsburgh&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.443486,-79.958245&amp;spn=0.010798,0.021038&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=university+of+pittsburgh&amp;aq=&amp;sll=40.431368,-79.9805&amp;sspn=0.142165,0.251656&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=university+of+pittsburgh&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.443486,-79.958245&amp;spn=0.010798,0.021038" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>', "street_view" = '<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=uni&amp;sll=40.444261,-79.970448&amp;sspn=0.142165,0.251656&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;ll=40.443486,-79.958245&amp;spn=0.010798,0.021038&amp;t=m&amp;layer=c&amp;cbll=40.441775,-79.956671&amp;panoid=BgWQKMiSI1fpwP7JUF16Vg&amp;cbp=12,45.25,,0,-3.34&amp;output=svembed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=uni&amp;sll=40.431368,-79.9805&amp;sspn=0.142165,0.251656&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;ll=40.443486,-79.958245&amp;spn=0.010798,0.021038&amp;t=m&amp;layer=c&amp;cbll=40.441775,-79.956671&amp;panoid=BgWQKMiSI1fpwP7JUF16Vg&amp;cbp=12,45.25,,0,-3.34" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>', "housing" = '<iframe src="http://www.tour.pitt.edu/tour-categories/residence-halls" scrolling="no" height="820" width="900"></iframe>', "food" = '<div style="overflow: hidden; max-width: 1000px;"><iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.pc.pitt.edu/dining/menus.php" style="margin-left: 0; height: 2000px; margin-top: -370px; margin-bottom: -375px; width: 750px;"></iframe></div>', "weather" = '<div style="overflow: hidden; max-width: 500px;"><iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.weather.com/weather/wxclimatology/monthly/graph/USPA1290" style="margin-left: -40px; height: 1570px; margin-top: -490px; width: 500px;"></iframe></div>', "dorms" = 'Towers (fr.)|Sutherland (fr.)|Lothrop (fr.)|Nordenberg (fr.)|Holland (fr.)|Forbes (fr.; honors)|McCormick|Brackenridge|Amos|Bruce|Panther|Pennsylvania|Ruskin|Bouquet Gardens|Oakwood Apartments|Centre-Plaza Apartments|Forbes-Craig Apartments (honors)', "dorm_urls" = 'towers|sutherland|lothrop|nordenberg|holland|forbes|mccormick|brackenridge|amos|bruce|panther|pennsylvania|ruskin|bouquet-gardens|oakwood-apartments|centre-plaza-apartments|forbes-craig-apartments', "science_majors" = 'Actuarial Mathematics|Applied Mathematics|Bioinformatics|Biological Sciences|Chemistry|Computer Science|Ecology and Evolution|Environmental Geology|Environmental Studies|Geology|History and Philosophy of Science|Linguistics|Mathematics|Mathematics-Economics|Mathematics-Philosophy|Microbiology|Molecular Biology|Natural Sciences Area|Neuroscience|Physics|Physics and Astronomy|Scientific Computing|Statistics', "social_science_majors" = 'Economics|Economics–Statistics|History|Political Science|Politics-Philosophy|Psychology|Sociology|Urban Studies', "humanities_majors" = 'Africana Studies|Africana Studies–English|Anthropology|Chinese|Classics|English Literature|English Writing|Film Studies|French|German|History of Art & Architecture|Humanities Area|Italian|Italian Studies|Japanese|Liberal Studies|Music|Philosophy|Religious Studies|Russian|Slavic Studies|Spanish|Studio Arts|Theatre Arts', "business_majors" = 'Accounting|Finance|General Management|Global Management|Marketing', "engineering_majors" = 'Bioengineering|Chemical Engineering|Civil Engineering|Computer Engineering|Electrical Engineering|Engineering Physics|Industrial Engineering|Materials Science and Engineering|Mechanical Engineering', "professional_majors" = 'Administration of Justice|Applied Developmental Psychology|Architectural Studies|Athletic Training|Clinical Dietetics and Nutrition|Communication: Rhet & Comm|Communication Science|Dental Hygiene|Emergency Medicine|Health Information Management|Health Services|Health and Physical Activity|Information Science|Legal Studies|Media and Professional Communications|Nursing|Pharmacy|Public Service|Rehabilitation Science|Social Work', "updated_at" = '2013-06-22 14:26:19.324611' WHERE "colleges"."id" = 1
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `exec_no_cache'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `block in exec_delete'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:670:in `exec_delete'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:96:in `update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:359:in `update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:68:in `update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:74:in `update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:71:in `update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:272:in `block in update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__1124092128366785760__update__948523398122619999__callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_update_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:272:in `update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:348:in `create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `block in create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__1124092128366785760__save__948523398122619999__callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:217:in `block in update_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:215:in `update_attributes'
/app/db/seeds.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:347:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
~/collegeanswerz >>
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130613023113) do

  create_table "colleges", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "public"
    t.string   "years"
    t.string   "category"
    t.string   "calendar"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "setting"
    t.integer  "retention"
    t.datetime "created_at",            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            :null => false
    t.integer  "graduation4"
    t.integer  "graduation6"
    t.string   "degrees"
    t.string   "rotc"
    t.integer  "sat_submit"
    t.integer  "act_submit"
    t.integer  "sat_math_25"
    t.integer  "sat_math_75"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_25"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_75"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_25"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_75"
    t.integer  "sat_composite_25"
    t.integer  "sat_composite_75"
    t.integer  "act_math_25"
    t.integer  "act_math_75"
    t.integer  "act_reading_25"
    t.integer  "act_reading_75"
    t.integer  "act_writing_75"
    t.integer  "act_composite_25"
    t.integer  "act_composite_75"
    t.integer  "acceptance_rate"
    t.integer  "enrolled"
    t.integer  "gpa375"
    t.integer  "gpa35"
    t.integer  "gpa325"
    t.integer  "gpa3"
    t.integer  "gpa25"
    t.integer  "high_school_tenth"
    t.integer  "high_school_quarter"
    t.integer  "high_school_half"
    t.integer  "sat_math_700"
    t.integer  "sat_math_600"
    t.integer  "sat_math_500"
    t.integer  "sat_math_400"
    t.integer  "sat_math_300"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_700"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_600"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_500"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_400"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_300"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_700"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_600"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_500"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_400"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_300"
    t.integer  "act_composite_30"
    t.integer  "act_composite_24"
    t.integer  "act_composite_18"
    t.integer  "act_composite_12"
    t.integer  "act_math_30"
    t.integer  "act_math_24"
    t.integer  "act_math_18"
    t.integer  "act_math_12"
    t.integer  "act_reading_30"
    t.integer  "act_reading_24"
    t.integer  "act_reading_18"
    t.integer  "act_reading_12"
    t.text     "very_important"
    t.text     "important"
    t.text     "considered"
    t.string   "student_faculty"
    t.integer  "class_20"
    t.integer  "class_49"
    t.integer  "class_50"
    t.text     "majors"
    t.integer  "law"
    t.integer  "business"
    t.integer  "medical"
    t.integer  "other_grad"
    t.integer  "us_news_ranking"
    t.text     "top_25_grad"
    t.integer  "enrollment"
    t.integer  "graduate_enrollment"
    t.integer  "in_state"
    t.integer  "out_of_state"
    t.integer  "male"
    t.integer  "female"
    t.text     "ethnicity"
    t.integer  "frats"
    t.integer  "sororities"
    t.integer  "on_campus"
    t.integer  "freshman_on_campus"
    t.integer  "in_state_tuition"
    t.integer  "out_of_state_tuition"
    t.integer  "room_and_board"
    t.integer  "with_need_got_aid"
    t.integer  "got_need_fully_met"
    t.integer  "percent_need_met"
    t.integer  "scholarships"
    t.integer  "loans"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "url"
    t.integer  "act_writing_25"
    t.integer  "cost_30"
    t.integer  "cost_48"
    t.integer  "cost_75"
    t.integer  "cost_110"
    t.integer  "cost_111"
    t.string   "requirements"
    t.string   "ap_credit"
    t.string   "scholarships_link"
    t.text     "map"
    t.text     "street_view"
    t.text     "housing"
    t.text     "food"
    t.text     "weather"
    t.text     "dorms"
    t.text     "majors_offered_link"
    t.text     "science_majors"
    t.text     "social_science_majors"
    t.text     "humanities_majors"
    t.text     "business_majors"
    t.text     "engineering_majors"
    t.text     "professional_majors"
    t.text     "dorm_urls"
  end

end
```

Updated Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130613023113) do

  create_table "colleges", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "public"
    t.string   "years"
    t.string   "category"
    t.string   "calendar"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "setting"
    t.integer  "retention"
    t.datetime "created_at",            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            :null => false
    t.integer  "graduation4"
    t.integer  "graduation6"
    t.string   "degrees"
    t.string   "rotc"
    t.integer  "sat_submit"
    t.integer  "act_submit"
    t.integer  "sat_math_25"
    t.integer  "sat_math_75"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_25"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_75"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_25"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_75"
    t.integer  "sat_composite_25"
    t.integer  "sat_composite_75"
    t.integer  "act_math_25"
    t.integer  "act_math_75"
    t.integer  "act_reading_25"
    t.integer  "act_reading_75"
    t.integer  "act_writing_75"
    t.integer  "act_composite_25"
    t.integer  "act_composite_75"
    t.integer  "acceptance_rate"
    t.integer  "enrolled"
    t.integer  "gpa375"
    t.integer  "gpa35"
    t.integer  "gpa325"
    t.integer  "gpa3"
    t.integer  "gpa25"
    t.integer  "high_school_tenth"
    t.integer  "high_school_quarter"
    t.integer  "high_school_half"
    t.integer  "sat_math_700"
    t.integer  "sat_math_600"
    t.integer  "sat_math_500"
    t.integer  "sat_math_400"
    t.integer  "sat_math_300"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_700"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_600"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_500"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_400"
    t.integer  "sat_reading_300"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_700"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_600"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_500"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_400"
    t.integer  "sat_writing_300"
    t.integer  "act_composite_30"
    t.integer  "act_composite_24"
    t.integer  "act_composite_18"
    t.integer  "act_composite_12"
    t.integer  "act_math_30"
    t.integer  "act_math_24"
    t.integer  "act_math_18"
    t.integer  "act_math_12"
    t.integer  "act_reading_30"
    t.integer  "act_reading_24"
    t.integer  "act_reading_18"
    t.integer  "act_reading_12"
    t.text     "very_important"
    t.text     "important"
    t.text     "considered"
    t.string   "student_faculty"
    t.integer  "class_20"
    t.integer  "class_49"
    t.integer  "class_50"
    t.text     "majors"
    t.integer  "law"
    t.integer  "business"
    t.integer  "medical"
    t.integer  "other_grad"
    t.integer  "us_news_ranking"
    t.text     "top_25_grad"
    t.integer  "enrollment"
    t.integer  "graduate_enrollment"
    t.integer  "in_state"
    t.integer  "out_of_state"
    t.integer  "male"
    t.integer  "female"
    t.text     "ethnicity"
    t.integer  "frats"
    t.integer  "sororities"
    t.integer  "on_campus"
    t.integer  "freshman_on_campus"
    t.integer  "in_state_tuition"
    t.integer  "out_of_state_tuition"
    t.integer  "room_and_board"
    t.integer  "with_need_got_aid"
    t.integer  "got_need_fully_met"
    t.integer  "percent_need_met"
    t.integer  "scholarships"
    t.integer  "loans"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "url"
    t.integer  "act_writing_25"
    t.integer  "cost_30"
    t.integer  "cost_48"
    t.integer  "cost_75"
    t.integer  "cost_110"
    t.integer  "cost_111"
    t.text     "requirements"
    t.text     "majors_offered"
    t.text     "ap_credit"
    t.text     "scholarships_link"
    t.text     "map"
    t.text     "street_view"
    t.text     "housing"
    t.text     "food"
    t.text     "weather"
    t.text     "dorms"
    t.text     "majors_offered_link"
    t.text     "science_majors"
    t.text     "social_science_majors"
    t.text     "humanities_majors"
    t.text     "business_majors"
    t.text     "engineering_majors"
    t.text     "professional_majors"
    t.text     "dorm_urls"
  end

end
```

Comment: This looks more like a spreadsheet than a database schema to me. I hope your next "migration" will normalize the structure upto at least 3NF.

Comment: i'm new to rails and i'm not too familiar with my options.  the idea is that my website has a page for each college, and I want to keep my code DRY by having one college view and altering the view based on the @college.attribute.  woud this be easier with a spreadsheet?  if so how do I use a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have PG admin? You could try running this in a SQL prompt where you can format it line by line and (hopefully) see which line is erroring, or cut out sections to try.

You can also check that the columns marked as `text` in the schema aren't limited to 255 characters.

Did you change any from string to text in a migrate? If so the limit may not have actually changed unless you specifically entered a new limit in the migrate.

Comment: I didn't download PG admin, so unless it comes standard, I don't have it.

I didn't do anything to limit the columns marked text.  Does that mean that they aren't limited to 255 characters?  If not, how do I check this?

Yes.  Some things were previously string but I changed them to text.  I changed the schema itself, and the migrations.  After changing the migrations I also ran `heroku run rake db:migrate`.  Is this my problem?  What can I do about it?

Comment: 1. You shouldn't change the schema, the schema file is generated for you. Delete the file and then: 2. You need to do `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=xxx` where xxx is the migration number of the changed file, this will run the `down` and the `up`, changing a migrate doesn't do anything unless you re-run it with `:redo` (which will also regenerate your schema file which should then more accurately reflect the database).

Comment: what about `heroku run rake db:migrate:redo`?

Comment: so I need to do `heroku run rake db:migrate:redo VERSON=XXX` for all the versions that are changed in addition to `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=XXX` for all the versions?

Comment: Nevermind, I just ran heroku run rake db:reset and it's all working!

Answer (score 1):

`'Application Essay|Character/Personal Qualities|Class Rank|Extracurricular Activities|First Generation College Student|Geographical Residence|Level of Applicant''s Interest|Racial/Ethnic Status|Recommendations|State Residency|Talent/Ability|Volunteer Work|Work Experience'`

This string is 270 characters!

Comment: It's not a string (I don't think).  see my schema as an edit to my question.